# how to compile java files classnotfoundexception

Tags: javac

I am having a java project having the directory structure as 
java->applet and a few .java files

the applet folder further contains two folders and some .java files

I need to develop a jar file out of this project

I did so by writing the command line

**jar cvfm myfile.jar *.java**
(obviously by moving into corresponding directory)

when I checked by extracting the file(it was zipped as a Nokia application installer file)
it showed me only the classes in the applet folder not the folders in it

moreover i needed to use this jar file in a jquery plugin where i had written

var dasherApplet = $('applet');

```
dasherApplet.attr({
    'height':'100%',
    'width':'100%',
    'archive':farfalla_path+'plugins/dasher/jardasher.jar',
    'code':'JDasherApplet.java'
});
```

but it showed me the class not found exception

for this I checked the previous versions of the java applet; there the java files were replaced by .class files so i tried compiling a java file into .class by using the command line

**C:/>javac filename.java**
still all in vain this time it showed me
 "cannot find symbol" error

what was interesting was that the errors generated were imitating the java files present in the same folder. I navigated to the directory where the file was stored still the same error
when i tried to simply run it by using
**java filename.java**
error was main class not found:JApplet.java

Please help me develop this applet

Comment: Do you have a public static void main(string[] args) {...} function in your filename.java class?

Comment: No it does not contain the required function. How can I add one.. what to write in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you need to compile all the jar files before running.

Secondly , you CANNOT run Applets using *java filename.java* .

As this link explains http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html ,

*jar cvf TicTacToe.jar TicTacToe.class audio images*

Here audio and images are folders , so that is how you add folders to jar.

Also .jar files are not Nokia Application Installer files . Nokia simply associates them for installing apps (that is J2ME)

Comment: it is giving me this error
javac: invalid flag: C:\filename.jar

Comment: may i seek further attention please

Comment: You cannot compile jar files but you have to individually compile all the .java files and then pack them into a jar and add a MANIFEST